# Maxwell's laws in presence of gravitational fields

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, metric-tensor, maxwell-equations

From what I know about maxwells laws, they are valid in inertial frames of reference.
But, any non inertial frame can be thought of as an inertial frame with a gravitational force. Hence, I logically conclude that maxwells laws hold only in those imertial frames which have no gravity

So do maxwells laws hold with existence of gravity?

We frequently solve problems of electromagnetism with frame of reference being earth, while also considering earths gravity. Is this correct or only an approximation?

Comment: The [Reissner Nordström](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/12.html) and [Kerr Newman](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=549#p549) metrics are solutions of the [Einstein Maxwell](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Einstein-Maxwell_equations) equations

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681609/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Gravity is so extremely weak compared to electromagnetism that Maxwell's equations work fine without any gravity terms in them, except in really unusual circumstances.